# Can a table have multiple editioning views in Oracle RDBMS 11

Tags: oracle, view, ddl

Can a table `ABC` have multiple editioning views in Oracle Database?

I have an editioning view `ABC` (created from table `ABC`) that shows the old edition to be `OLD_EDITION_1` as its `edition_name` in the `USER_OBJECTS` table. I am trying to create a new editioning view named `ABC` with an edition name of `NEW_EDITION_2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one editioning view per table in each edition.

To explain, some background. Edition-based redefinition (EBR) brought two new schema objects:

- Editions
- Editioning views

Editions extend the namespace for an object. This prefixes the schema. So the fully-qualified name of an object in Oracle Database from 11.2 is:

```
edition_name.schema_name.object_name
```

But you can't explicitly reference the edition_name. It is part of your session settings. When you create an editionable object, it goes in your current edition.

For example, the following creates a new user, editions enables it, creates the table "abc" and the editioning view "ABC":

```
grant create session, create table, create view, unlimited tablespace to
  usr identified by usr;
alter user usr enable editions;

create edition e1;

grant use on edition e1 to usr;

conn usr/usr

create table "abc" (
  c1 int, 
  c2 int
);
create or replace editioning view abc as 
  select * from "abc";

select object_name, object_type, edition_name
from   user_objects;

OBJECT_NAME   OBJECT_TYPE   EDITION_NAME   
abc           TABLE         <null>         
ABC           VIEW          ORA$BASE
```

If you try and create a new version of the view in the edition e1, you'll get an error:

```
create or replace editioning view e1.abc as 
  select c1 from "abc";

ORA-01917: user or role 'E1' does not exist
```

This is because you're currently in the edition ora$base. The default for every database.

To create a new version of the view, you need to switch your session to edition e1:

```
alter session set edition = e1;

create or replace editioning view abc as 
  select * from "abc";

select object_name, object_type, edition_name
from   user_objects;

OBJECT_NAME   OBJECT_TYPE   EDITION_NAME   
abc           TABLE         <null>         
ABC           VIEW          E1   

select object_name, object_type, edition_name
from   user_objects_ae;

OBJECT_NAME   OBJECT_TYPE   EDITION_NAME   
abc           TABLE         <null>         
ABC           VIEW          E1             
ABC           VIEW          ORA$BASE
```

As you see, you now have two views "ABC". One in each edition.

If, still in E1, you try and create a new editioning view using "abc", you'll get an error:

```
create or replace editioning view abc_new as 
  select * from "abc";

ORA-42300: an Editioning view is already defined on this table
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on Oracle 11g release 2:

Your editioning view name and table name should **not** be the same.  From https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/edition-based-redefinition%2c-part-2 the sequence of events are:

1. `Alter table ABC rename to ABC_RT;`
2. `create editioning view ABC as select /* column list here */ from ABC_RT;`
3. Then create your new edition, make that edition the current edition, then create a new editioning view ABC.

You need to look at the data dictionary view `USER_OBJECTS_AE` also, instead of `USER_OBJECTS`